# grep: How to capture matches into variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

say I have a text file that looks like this:

```
foo: foo.txt
bar: baz.txt

quux: quux.txt
```

I want to run a `grep` query such that the first and fourth lines match, while the second and third do not. Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
grep '(capture the word): (ensure the same word is used here)\.txt' file.txt
```

How would I express this using `grep`? I'm sorry if this is a naive question, but I'm not well-versed in regular expressions so please forgive me.

Comment: Does an empty line "not match"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -E '([^:]+): \1\.txt'` should work.
See https://regex101.com/r/qO3dO6/1 for how.

Edit:
With inspiration from @walter-a

`grep -E '(.*): \1\.txt'` also matches: `strange:foo: strange:foo.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Funny. I started with sed and found about the same solution as @jandob. My solution will accept `strange:foo: strange:foo.txt`

```
sed -n '/\(.*\): \1\.txt/p' file
```

Edit: Looking for `oops: ops.txt` and `foo: foo.txtbook`

```
sed -n '/^\(.*\): \1\.txt$/p' file
```

Comment: True but if the `.txt` extension is not needed, e.g. `sed -n '/\(.*\): \1/p' file` also matches `bar: baz`. E.g. https://regex101.com/r/aL2jN3/1

Answer (score 1):

I would use awk to do this:

```
awk -F': *' 'BEGIN { f = 1 }
    f && (NR == 1 || NR == 4) { f = NF == 2 && $1 ".txt" == $2 } 
    f && (NR == 2 || NR == 3) { f = NF != 2 || $1 ".txt" != $2 }
    END { if (f) print "1st and 4th lines match, 2nd and 3rd do not" }' file
```

- Before processing the file, `f` is set to true.
- The first block is executed on the first and fourth lines, as long as `f` is still true. `f` stays true if there are two fields and the first matches the second after `.txt` has been added.
- The second block is executed on the second and third lines, as long as `f` is still true. `f` stays true if there aren't two fields (e.g. an empty line) or they don't match.
- After processing the file, the message is printed if `f` is still true.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in the folder where these files are listed,

find *.txt  | cut -d. -f1 | grep -v bar | grep -v ^$ | while read line
do
print " ${line} : ${line}.txt "

find - will list files in the folder with .txt ext.
cut - will get first part before .txt. 
grep -v will omit unwanted lines.
Next grep -will grep wanted lines
While loop- will iterate through remaining line.
print - will print in desired format

Answer (score 0):

FWIW here's a solution that will work in all awks on all systems:

```
$ awk -F'[: .]+' 'NF && $1==$2' file
foo: foo.txt
quux: quux.txt
```

Comment: Adding `&& $3=="txt" && NF==3'` will help against `foo: foo.skipme` but not against `x::::::x.txt`.

Comment: There's no hint in the question or the posted sample input that any of that might be useful.